# colourful icon for a custom activity in uiactivityviewcontroller.?

Tags: ios7

i am new to iOS .i want colorful icon for custom activity in UIActivityViewController.please help me out.i have tried a lot but cant get proper solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an underscore to the method in your custom UIActivity class

```
- (UIImage *)_activityImage {}
```

Your colourful image will display

Comment: Isn't this a private API?